# Buttons with different size images from sprite as background, images not placed correctly

Tags: javascript, html, css, sprite

I create some buttons, with images from a sprite to be used as the background for them. Each button is contained within its own `<figure>`. When the button is selected, the full size image from the Sprite should be displayed. The full size images are displayed correctly, but the thumbnail images on the buttons aren’t in the right positions.

Part of the Blue thumbnail  appears with the Red shape thumbnail.
The rest of the Blue shape thumbnail appears where the full blue thumbnail should be, and the Green thumbnail is tacked onto it.
Nothing appears where the Green shape thumbnail should be.

This is what is displayed.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HGi9F.jpg)

Here’s the relevant part of my code. What am I doing wrong?

The CSS

```
#img1, #img2, #img3,
#thumb1, #thumb2, #thumb3 {
  background: url("colours-full.jpeg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  object-fit: none;
}

#thumb1, #thumb2, #thumb3 {
  width: 30em;
  height: 30em;
  background-size: cover;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 1.5em;
}

#img1 {object-position: 0 0;
  width:  422px;
  height: 287px;
}
#thumb1 { background-position: 0 0; }

#img2 {object-position: -422px 0;
  width:  374px;
  height: 374px;
}
#thumb2 { background-position: -30em 0; }

#img3 {object-position: -796px 0;
  width:  151px;
  height: 560px;
}
#thumb3 { background-position: -60em 0; }
```

The button creation

```
function imgBtn (figNum) {
//  Insert a button with thumbnail image
    let html = '<button type="button" ' +
                       'id="thumb' + figNum +
                     '" onclick="showBigImg (' + figNum + ')"></button>';

    const figcap = document.getElementById("fig" + figNum).firstElementChild;
    figcap.insertAdjacentHTML ("afterend", html);  /* Append the button to 
                                                      the figcaption */
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason you're not giving each button it's own image?  There are a few things here that are a bit strange, although probably not necessarily wrong.  Using em for positioning probably isn't recommended as it's font size.  Despite that I'd have to take a punt and say that "float" may not be your friend here, and "overflow: hidden" *may* help. In this scenario, I often find it helpful to just change the background to a solid colour first, play around with it in the browser inspector and make sure that your buttons are being positioned correctly first, THEN play with the image.

Comment: I am trying to give each button it’s own image: bottom 1 is the red shape; button 2 is the blue; & button 3 is green.  Taking out the float:left makes things worse.  I tried adding objects position, width, & Height to the buttons. Didn’t improve things much.